# Node JS asynchronous calls with AWS api

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous

I'm having trouble with node.js and using the AWS api to get information on RDS instances. Most of the information is being returned when the page renders, but before the API call for the database "tag" completes, the databases are being returned to the page.

```
var dbInstances = [];
  var rds = new AWS.RDS();
  rds.describeDBInstances({}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    //loop through all databases that were returned and pull out the info we need.
    data.DBInstances.forEach(function(dbInstance) {
      dbInstance.Name = dbInstance.DBInstanceIdentifier;
      dbInstance.Status = dbInstance.DBInstanceStatus;

      //we need to look up the tags for the current db instance.
      rds.listTagsForResource({ResourceName: dbInstance.DBInstanceArn},
        function(tagerr, tagdata) {
        //loop through all the tags of the specified db instance.
        if (tagerr) console.log(tagerr);
        if (tagdata !== null) {
          var tags = tagdata.TagList || [];
          tags.forEach(function(tag) {
            //Look to see if the database has the "Group" tag
            if (tag.Key === "Group") {
              dbInstance.Group = tag.Value;
            }
          });
        }
      });
      //put it in our databases array.
      dbInstances.push(dbInstance);
    });
    //prepare view model
    var viewObj2 = {
      "region": regionObj.Name,
      "dbInstances": dbInstances
    };
    //render view model.
    res.render('instances', viewObj2);
  });
});
```

When the page is rendered, I have the info below:

```
NAME     GROUP      STATUS
Db1                 running
Db2                 stopped
Db3                 running
....
```

As you can see, my 'Group' information is all missing because node method returns the database array before the "rds.listTagsForResource" call is complete. I've been able to figure out the other asynchronicity related bugs in my code and used callbacks to address them, mostly. However no matter how I set the callbacks up in this particular chunk of code, I'm not getting the data I need.

How can I make this work?

And yes, I have confirmed that there are dbInstance tags by logging them. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [promise variants in the SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html) e.g. `rds.listTagsForResource(res).promise()` and then using the standard [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for the promises to be fulfilled.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!